# Stored procedure containing inner join with count not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say i've got a databasetable looking a bit like this, containing information about some assignments.

```
Id   | ProfessionId      | Title       | Deadline     | DateCreated | ClosingDate
1    |  5                | Something   | 01-12-2012   | 05-11-2012  | 12-11-2012
2    |  6                | Something   | 01-12-2012   | 05-11-2012  | 12-11-2012
3    |  7                | Something   | 01-12-2012   | 05-11-2012  | 12-11-2012
4    |  7                | Something   | 01-12-2012   | 05-11-2012  | 12-11-2012
```

I want to generate an overview foreach profession (assignments belong to a certain profession) and count the number of assignment in each profession. The overview coming from the database should look like this;

```
Id | Name           | FriendlyUrl     | Ordinal   | NumberOfAssignments
5  | Profession 1   | profession-1    | 1         | 1
6  | Profession 2   | profession-2    | 1         | 1
7  | Profession 3   | profession-3    | 1         | 2
8  | Profession 4   | profession-4    | 1         | 0
```

I've currently got a stored procedure returning the overview above, except that the amount of assignments isn't correct. Assignments with a closingdate in the past (we then assume the assignment is closed) shouldn't be taken into the the total number of assignment.

The current stored procedure is like this:

```
BEGIN
    SELECT  p.Id, 
            p.Naam, 
            p.FriendlyUrl, 
            p.Ordinal, 
            COUNT(a.ProfessionId) AS NumberOfAssignments
    FROM ME_Profession AS p 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ME_Assignment AS a ON a.ProfessionId = p.Id
    INNER JOIN ME_Client AS c ON a.ClientId = c.Id
    INNER JOIN aspnet_Membership AS m ON m.UserId = c.UserId
    WHERE m.IsApproved = 1 
    GROUP BY p.Id, p.Naam, p.FriendlyUrl, p.Ordinal
END
```

I've already came up with and modified procedure like the one below, but it doesn't work. It feels like i'm either thinking too difficult or missing something obvious. What could go wrong?

```
SELECT        p.Id, p.Naam, p.FriendlyUrl, p.Ordinal, pc.NumberOfAssignments
FROM            ME_Profession AS p 
INNER JOIN ME_Assignment AS a ON a.ProfessionId = p.Id 
INNER JOIN ME_Client AS c ON a.ClientId = c.Id
INNER JOIN aspnet_Membership AS m ON m.UserId = c.UserId
INNER JOIN (SELECT a2.ProfessionId, COUNT(*) AS NumberOfAssignments FROM ME_Assignment AS a2 GROUP BY a2.ProfessionId WHERE a2.Closingdate > GETDATE()) pc ON p.ProfessionId = pc.ProfessionId
WHERE        m.IsApproved = 1 AND a.Closingdate > GETDATE()
GROUP BY p.Id, p.Naam, p.FriendlyUrl, p.Ordinal
```

**UPDATE 1:** Added where condition for date

Comment: Forgive me if I'm missing the obvious, but what prevents you from simply adding another condition to your WHERE clause? Such as: `AND a.ClosingDate > GETDATE()`

Comment: That gives me no results at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that you need to join against the table `ME_profession` again, try this:

```
SELECT  p.Id, p.Naam, p.FriendlyUrl, p.Ordinal, pc.NumberOfAssignments,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN ClosingDate > GETDATE() OR ClosingDate IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS NumberOfAssignments 
FROM  ME_Profession AS p 
INNER JOIN ME_Assignment AS a 
    ON a.ProfessionId = p.Id 
INNER JOIN ME_Client AS c 
    ON a.ClientId = c.Id
INNER JOIN aspnet_Membership AS m 
    ON m.UserId = c.UserId
WHERE (m.IsApproved = 1)
GROUP BY p.Id, p.Naam, p.FriendlyUrl, p.Ordinal
```

Comment: Great and easy solution, thanks! Which everything was this simple:)

Answer (score 1):

How about ... LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM ME_Assignment WHERE ClosingDate > GETDATE()) as a ...

Answer (score 0):

I don't see criteria in the current stored procedure that would satisfy this statement:

> Assignments with a closingdate in the past (we then assume the
>   assignment is closed) shouldn't be taken into the the total number of
>   assignment.

It may be you simply need to add the criteria you have in your work in progress to the existing proc:

```
WHERE ClosingDate > GETDATE()
```

Comment: I already tried this, but unfortunately this doesn't give me any results at all.

Comment: I'm betting the reason he's getting no results is because the `OUTER JOIN` is never finding a matching join row, which causes `ClosingDate > GETDATE()` to always be false for a null `ClosingDate` column. The fix for this would be to instead use `(ClosingDate > GETDATE() OR ClosingDate IS NULL)`